# Endless background tasks in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, background, task

When I opened Intellij Idea, I was faced with endless tasks in the background. What is the reason of this?

Although I waited a long time for these missions, they did not stop.The solution for me was to completely uninstall and reinstall the app.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiEH4.jpg)